# Comparing Decimal values in Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have the following Ecto schema and query, and am trying to figure out the proper way to compare `Decimal` values.

**Schema:**

```
schema "products" do
  field(:price, :decimal)
end
```

**Query:**

```
from(
  p in Product,
  where: p.price <= ^max_price
)
```

This seems to work fine when the price happens to be an integer (still stored as `#Decimal<integer_value>` though). However, whenever `product.price` is a float (e.g. `#Decimal<1000.00>`, I get the wrong results returned.

The Decimal library even says that comparison using `<` etc is incorrect when using Decimals. However, how would one go about doing a comparison when used with Ecto?

Comment: Can you elaborate the "wrong results" you are getting?

Comment: For example, if `max_price` is 100.00, I'd see products being returned with a price of `1000.00`

Comment: Which database are you using? What is the type you used for the price field in the migration?

Comment: Postgres, so `postgrex: 0.13.5`. The migration is defined as `add :price, :decimal`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, one (or both) of the variables are of the `Decimal` type. That means the problem is that you are not comparing actual values, but Structs. That will give inconsistent results. For example:

```
iex> Decimal.new(-1) > Decimal.new(0)
true
```

You need to use the [`Decimal.compare/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/Decimal.html#compare/2) method.

---

**But in the context of Ecto Queries,** these comparisons are [automatically handled](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/764) by the underlying database and its Elixir adapter. You are probably using an older database driver/adapter that doesn't implement it correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately you are unable to use `Decimal.comare/2` in an ecto query. When using a query, it is the database that does the comparison, not Elixir.

Comment: Hmmm, OK. I'll dig into that some more. Perhaps I have an issue elsewhere.